# pass src attribute to iframe in a loop

Tags: php, iframe, src

i am passing source attribute to iframe from source Array that is consisting URL of different videos. but the problem is iframe take only first index of source array in each alteration of loop.
Code is given below.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.close').click(function(){      
        $('iframe#myVideo1aV').attr('src', $('iframe#myVideo1aV').attr('src'));

    });
});
</script>

    <?php     $src=array("http://player.vimeo.com/video/182048025","http://www.youtube.com/embed/L7ZQ0o1Gp5Y","http://player.vimeo.com/video/182048025");

        $sq = "Select * from videos_topics;
        $result = $con->query($sq);
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {?>
        <div class="input-group">

        <button class="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal" ><?php 
         echo $row['video'] ;?></button>
        </div>

        <div class="modal"  id="Modal" role="dialog">
           <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
             <div class="modal-content" style="background-color:black">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <iframe id="myVideo1aV" width="100%" height="400" <?php echo 'src="'.$src[$i].'" ';?>frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php  
     $i++;
    }?>
```

Comment: Where is the actual loop then? If you are outputting the whole HTML block you have shown inside a loop, then you would be creating duplicate IDs, which is not allowed in HTML, so that is the first thing you need to go fix. And there is nothing dynamic about `src="srcArray[index]"`, that is just a src attribute referring to the static “URL” `srcArray[index]`

Comment: hay @misorude i have edit the code please check it again .

Comment: _“but the problem is iframe take only first index of source array in each alteration of loop”_ - does it really …? Check the generated HTML source code that gets output by your script.